# asp.net core - get User at Service Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I use ASP.NET Core 2.1 and would like to fetch `User` at a **service level**.

I've seen examples when `HttpContextAccessor` gets injected into some service and then we fetch the current `User` via `UserManager`

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(accessor.HttpContext.User);
```

or in controller

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

---

Problems:

- Injecting `HttpContextAccessor` into service seems to be **wrong** - simply because we violate SRP and the *Service Layer* isn't isolated  (it is dependant on *http context*).
- We can of course **fetch user in a controller** (a somewhat better approach), but we face a dilemma - we simply don't want to pass `User` as parameter in every single service method

---

### I spent a few hours thinking about how best to implement it and have come up with a solution.

I'm just not entirely sure my approach is adequate and doesn't violate any of the software-design principles.

**Sharing my code in hopes to get recommendations from StackOverflow community.**

The idea is the following:

First, I introduce `SessionProvider` which is registered as Singleton.

```
services.AddSingleton<SessionProvider>();
```

`SessionProvider` has a `Session` property which holds `User`, `Tenant`, etc.

Secondly, I introduce `SessionMiddleware` and register it

```
app.UseMiddleware<SessionMiddleware>();
```

In the `Invoke` method I resolve `HttpContext`, `SessionProvider` & `UserManager`.

- I fetch `User`
- Then I initialise `Session` property of `ServiceProvider` singleton:

`sessionProvider.Initialise(user);`

At this stage `ServiceProvider` has `Session` object containing the info we need.

Now we inject `SessionProvider` into any service and its `Session` object is ready for use.

---

**Code:**

`SessionProvider`:

```
public class SessionProvider
{
    public Session Session;

    public SessionProvider(
        )
    {
        Session = new Session();
    }

    public void Initialise(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        Session.User = user;
        Session.UserId = user.Id;
        Session.Tenant = user.Tenant;
        Session.TenantId = user.TenantId;
        Session.Subdomain = user.Tenant.HostName;
    }
}
```

`Session`:

```
public class Session
{
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

    public long? UserId { get; set; }

    public int? TenantId { get; set; }

    public string Subdomain { get; set; }
}
```

`SessionMiddleware`:

```
public class SessionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public SessionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(
        HttpContext context,
        SessionProvider sessionProvider,
        MultiTenancyUserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
        )
    {
        await next(context);

        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);

        if (user != null)
        {
            sessionProvider.Initialise(user);
        }
    }
}
```

And now **Service Layer** code:

```
public class BaseService
{
    public readonly AppDbContext Context;
    public Session Session;

    public BaseService(
        AppDbContext context,
        SessionProvider sessionProvider
        )
    {
        Context = context;
        Session = sessionProvider.Session;
    }
}
```

So this is the *base* class for any service, as you can see we can now fetch `Session` object easily and it's ready for use:

```
public class VocabularyService : BaseService, IVocabularyService
{
    private readonly IVocabularyHighPerformanceService _vocabularyHighPerformanceService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public VocabularyService(
        AppDbContext context,
        IVocabularyHighPerformanceService vocabularyHighPerformanceService,
        SessionProvider sessionProvider,
        IMapper mapper
        ) : base(
              context,
              sessionProvider
              )
    {
        _vocabularyHighPerformanceService = vocabularyHighPerformanceService;
        _mapper = mapper; 
    }

    public async Task<List<VocabularyDto>> GetAll()
    {
        List<VocabularyDto> dtos = _vocabularyHighPerformanceService.GetAll(Session.TenantId.Value);
        dtos = dtos.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
        return await Task.FromResult(dtos);
    }
}
```

Focus on the following bit:

```
.GetAll(Session.TenantId.Value);
```

also, we can easily get current user

```
Session.UserId.Value
```

or

```
Session.User
```

**Update 1** - `VocabularyController.cs`

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[Authorize]
public class VocabularyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IVocabularyService _vocabularyService;

    public VocabularyController(
        IVocabularyService vocabularyService
        )
    {
        _vocabularyService = vocabularyService;
    }

    public async Task<List<VocabularyDto>> GetAll()
    {
        var result = await _vocabularyService.GetAll();
        return result;
    }
}
```

So, that's it.

*I tested my code and it works well when several tabs are open - each tab has different subdomain in url*.

*(Tenant is resolved from subdomain - the data is being fetched correctly)*

---

**Maybe some of you have a better idea of how to implement this?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _from StackOverflow community_ - have you cross-posted it? This is Code Review ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t I've got a recommendation to use `codereview` portal for questions like this.

Comment: What's with that: `...`? It looks like you have removed parts of you code. Please don't do it. It'll backfire - it always does. Post what you have unchanged.

Comment: Well, this is still wrong. You're using variables that aren't even initialized :-| On Code Review we require complete and working code. Pseudocode or incomplete code is off-topic.

Comment: @t3chb0t Yeah sorry, my oversight. Looks better now?

Comment: Not really. It shouldn't look good. It shoud be real. `_vocabularyHighPerformanceService = vocabularyHighPerformanceService;` - this line wouldn't compile. there is no `vocabularyHighPerformanceService` argument. Why don't you just copy/paste what you have?

Comment: @t3chb0t Right, pardon my clumsiness with this one. Right now `VocabularyService` is complete. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: How about the rest? Do we see the actual code or is it edited too? ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t My app consists of 2 solutions - Angular 6 and ASP.NET Core.
Could you please give me more details as to which files are required for the question?
Am I right in thinking adding `Controller` would do? Or do I also need to attach code from `Startup.cs`?

Comment: Generally you just need to post what is relevant to your question. If you think other parts might be important then why not, although `Startup.cs`is mostly just registration. If you're not doing anything _weird_ there, then you might skip it. BUT when you post something, please make sure it's not simplified or edited in anyway that would make it incomplete. The best you can do is just copy/paste your actual code ;-)

Comment: Injecting SessionProvider as a singleton is not thread safe, a new SessionProvider instance should be allocated for each request, so it is best to inject as Scoped

Answer (score 3):

Here's a better workaround in my opinion - we no longer make a DB call **per every single request**, we just retrieve UserID & TenantID from Claims instead:

Please note that the lifetime of `SessionContext` is Per Request - when the request starts we hook into it, resolve `SessionContext` instance, then populating it with `UserID` & `TenantID` - after this wherever we inject our `SessionContext` (given the same request) - it will contain the values we need.

```
services.AddScoped<SessionContext>();
```

`SessionContext.cs`

```
public class SessionContext
{
    public long? UserId { get; set; }

    public int? TenantId { get; set; }

    public string Subdomain { get; set; }
}
```

`SessionFilter.cs`

```
public class SessionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
        ActionExecutingContext context,
        ActionExecutionDelegate next
        )
    {
        var services = context.HttpContext.RequestServices;
        var session = services.GetService(typeof(SessionContext)) as SessionContext;

        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.HttpContext.User.Identity;

        var userIdClaim = claimsIdentity.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == CustomClaims.UserId);
        if (userIdClaim != null)
        {
            session.UserId = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userIdClaim.Value) ? long.Parse(userIdClaim.Value) : (long?)null;
        }

        var tenantIdClaim = claimsIdentity.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == CustomClaims.TenantId);
        if (tenantIdClaim != null)
        {
            session.TenantId = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantIdClaim.Value) ? int.Parse(tenantIdClaim.Value) : (int?)null;
        }

        session.Subdomain = context.HttpContext.Request.GetSubDomain();

        var resultContext = await next();
    }
}
```

`AuthController.cs`

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<AuthenticateOutput> Authenticate([FromBody] AuthenticateInput input)
{
    var expires = input.RememberMe ? DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(5) : DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20);

    string subdomain = HttpContext.Request.GetSubDomain();
    _tenantService.SetSubDomain(subdomain);
    var user = await _userService.Authenticate(input.UserName, input.Password);

    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unauthorised");
    }

    int? tenantId = _tenantService.GetTenantId();
    string strTenantId = tenantId.HasValue ? tenantId.ToString() : string.Empty;

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Expires = expires,
        Issuer = _config.GetValidIssuer(),
        Audience = _config.GetValidAudience(),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_config.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
            // claims required for SessionContext
            new Claim(CustomClaims.UserId, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(CustomClaims.TenantId, strTenantId)
        })
    };

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    string tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    return new AuthenticateOutput() { Token = tokenString };
}
```